# numberOfRowsInSection count sets all section rows to the first sections count

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm trying to set this sectioned table up to display different JSON arrays in different sections but for some reason if i have a bigger row count in any section after the first section i get [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2].
This is how i've got each sections row count set up, the arrays are being set up on viewdidload and i call to reload once i've got all the arrays filled

`[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return [_team1 count];
        break;

    case 1:
        return [_team2 count];
        break;
    case 2:
        return [_team3 count];
        break;
    case 3:
        return [_team4 count];
        break;
    case 4:
        return [_team5 count];
        break;

    default:
        return section;
        break;
}
```

}

And for cellForRowAtIndex i have this, Team1 - Team5 are Dictionary Classes i've used for populating the array from the JSON:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
Team1 *team1= [_team1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team2 *team2= [_team2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team3 *team3= [_team3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team4 *team4= [_team4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team5 *team5= [_team5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TeamCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
isShowingDetails = NO;
for(UILabel *v in cell.details)
{
    v.alpha = 0;
}
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

if(indexPath.section == 0){
    [cell.name setText:team1.name];
    [cell.institute setText:team1.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team1.line];
    [cell.email setText:team1.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team1.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team1.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team1.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team1.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team1.link];

}
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    [cell.institute setText:team2.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team2.line];
    [cell.email setText:team2.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team2.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team2.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team2.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team2.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team2.link];
}

if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    [cell.institute setText:team3.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team3.line];
    [cell.email setText:team3.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team3.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team3.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team3.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team3.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team3.link];
}
if(indexPath.section == 3)
{
    [cell.institute setText:team4.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team4.line];
    [cell.email setText:team4.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team4.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team4.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team4.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team4.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team4.link];
}

if(indexPath.section == 4)
{
    [cell.institute setText:team5.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team5.line];
    [cell.email setText:team5.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team5.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team5.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team5.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team5.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team5.link];
}






cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

}

Comment: How about your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because you retrieve `Team`'s detail out of switch section. Just move it inside.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TeamCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
isShowingDetails = NO;
for(UILabel *v in cell.details)
{
    v.alpha = 0;
}
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

if(indexPath.section == 0){
    Team1 *team1= [_team1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.name setText:team1.name];
    [cell.institute setText:team1.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team1.line];
    [cell.email setText:team1.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team1.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team1.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team1.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team1.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team1.link];

}
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    Team2 *team2= [_team2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.institute setText:team2.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team2.line];
    [cell.email setText:team2.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team2.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team2.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team2.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team2.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team2.link];
}

if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    Team3 *team3= [_team3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.institute setText:team3.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team3.line];
    [cell.email setText:team3.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team3.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team3.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team3.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team3.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team3.link];
}
if(indexPath.section == 3)
{
    Team4 *team4= [_team4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.institute setText:team4.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team4.line];
    [cell.email setText:team4.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team4.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team4.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team4.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team4.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team4.link];
}

if(indexPath.section == 4)
{
    Team5 *team5= [_team5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.institute setText:team5.institute];
    [cell.line setText:team5.line];
    [cell.email setText:team5.email];
    [cell.mobile setText:team5.mobile];
    [cell.postal setText:team5.postal];
    [cell.instituteAdd setText:team5.office];
    [cell.instituteWeb setText:team5.web];
    [cell.linkedWeb setText:team5.link];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

By the way, this is not optimise when you create 5 classes for 5 teams while they have the same properties and stand for the same entities. What if you have more than 5 teams? Think about it! Hope that help :)

Comment: Wow! I would have never had thought to do that! i always thought that it would just populate it like that, thanks heap!

Answer (score -1):

The bug is quite obvious:

```
Team1 *team1= [_team1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team2 *team2= [_team2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team3 *team3= [_team3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team4 *team4= [_team4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Team5 *team5= [_team5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Let's say section 4 (_team5) has 3 rows 0 to 2, while the others have only two. Eventually, your method will be called to get row 2 of section 4. _team5 has an object at index 2, but the other teams don't, so you crash.

```
NSArray* teams = nil;
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0: teams = _team1; break;
    case 1: teams = _team2; break;
    case 2: teams = _team3; break;
    case 3: teams = _team4; break;
    case 4: teams = _team5; break;
}
```

etc.

You don't really have different classes for Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, do you? I mean surely not? That would be ridiculous.